# How can i subtract the background from an image in mahotas and opencv in python?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, mahotas

I have many image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXLS5.jpg) or like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3fWs.jpg) and i use this code:

```
fork = mh.imread(path)
bin = fork[:,:,0]
bin = mh.erode(bin)
bin = (bin < 80)
```

for the 2nd image, but i have to use this:

```
bin = (bin < 127)
```

for the first.

There is a way for automatically obtain a good image without background, or i have to choose a median value hopefully is good for the most of my images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a threshold value that is called "Otsu Threshold". [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) you have more information.

You can use [`otsu`](http://mahotas.readthedocs.org/en/latest/thresholding.html) to do it in Mahotas or [`threshold_otsu`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_otsu.html) in [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/):

```
fork = mh.imread(path)
bin = fork[:,:,0]
thresh = mh.otsu(bin)
binary =( bin< thresh)
```

Comment: I wouldn't call Otsu "optimal" as it is not always appropriate. Perhaps, "there is an automated method... , which works well when the foreground is well separated."

Comment: Well, I used mh.otsu in the first image and it does not work: the left side of the image is almost all white! THere is other stuff to do, maybe?

Comment: As suggested by @luispedro I removed the word "optimal"

Comment: @postgres You have problems with the illumination. You need to perform some histogram equalization prior to use Otsu. Here you have more information: http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.9.x/auto_examples/plot_equalize.html

Comment: Oh thanks! It works, but for converting the image from scikit to mahotas? i used this:     binimg = np.array(img_adapteq, dtype=np.uint8) and i got a total black image!

Comment: @postgres I am not familiar with mahotas, but why do you need to convert to mahotas? If you installed scikit image, you can use `threshold_otsu()` from scikit

Comment: because i used also dilation, erosion, close function and other stuff in mahotas, i know that they are also in scikit, but using dtype the image conversion was good from other libreries like cv2 and scikit

Comment: i tried this binimg = binimg > 0.5 but all values are converted in False. Moreover, i receive that warning: File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\skimage\exposure\exposure.py", line 51
    warnings.warn("This might be a color image. The histogram will be "
UserWarning: This might be a color image. The histogram will be computed on the flattened image. You can instead apply this function to each color channel.

Comment: i  did these steps: 1) imread(image) 2) histogram equalization 3) conversion with binimg > 0.5 or np.array(img_adapteq, dtype=np.uint16) 4) binarization mhgray[:,:,0] 5) otsu binimg = binimg > 0.5 thresh = mh.otsu(binimg)

Comment: @postgres I don't understand the code you posted... but It seems that your `binimg` is a N-Dimensional array and not a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to separate the white background from the image.
Here are the steps to do this. I will write in plain English, because I am not familiar with python.

1: Calculate closing of the image (application of dilation and than erosion). Use structural element as square of size 5x5 for dilation and erosion.

```
C = mh.dilate(bin)
C = mh.erode(C);
```

This will give you the background

2: Subtract the background from the original image:

```
C = C-bin
```

This will give you an image of the star painted in white and the background is black

3: Now calculate automatic threshold for binarization. Use simple Otsu technique to estimate the best threshold. In openCV this is something like:

```
double thresh = cv::threshold(im,im,0,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
cv::threshold(im,im,thresh,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

This will give you perfect results for your images. 
Do not try to guess the threshold. It is not 80 and not 127 for your images. Use Otsu