# Why after histogram equalization (scikit image) and Otsu mahotas method in some images get out big white squares?

Tags: image-processing, scikit-image, mahotas

I used histogram equalization and adaptation for erase illumination from the grayscale images:

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
import pymorph as pm
import mahotas as mh
from skimage import morphology
from skimage import io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import data, img_as_float
from skimage import exposure

mhgray = io.imread(path)
mhgray = mhgray[:,:,0]

#thresh = mh.otsu(binimg)
#gray =( binimg< thresh)
img = color.rgb2gray(mhgray)   
#img = mhgray #binimg

#from skimage import exposure
#print dir(exposure)

# Contrast stretching
p2 = np.percentile(img, 2)
p98 = np.percentile(img, 98)
#img_rescale = exposure.rescale_intensity(img, in_range=(p2, p98))
img_rescale = exposure.rescale_intensity(img, out_range=(0, 255))

# Equalization
img_eq = exposure.equalize_hist(img)

# Adaptive Equalization
img_adapteq = exposure.equalize_adapthist(img, clip_limit=0.03)
```

but after the [histogram equalization](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.9.x/auto_examples/plot_equalize.html), i use otsu method:

```
thresh = mh.otsu(binimg) 
gray =( binimg< thresh)
```

the thresh value for the next example is: 16329

Source image:

[image]

After histogram equalization and adaptation:

[image: source image]

After Otsu method:

[image: Image after Otsu]

The image before Otsu is an array of uint16, after Otsu is a numpy array of bool.

In [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152497/how-can-i-subtract-the-background-from-an-image-in-mahotas-and-opencv-in-python) suggested me to use histogram equalization to avoid illumination problems.

It is for the grey background?
How can i fix it?

Comment: Please provide a copy of the input image.

Comment: Sorry: source image: http://i.imgur.com/7AEJTuA.jpg

Comment: another image: http://i.imgur.com/drhsyfL.jpg and the result is: http://i.imgur.com/21tKYJv.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a dilation command to the above example:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
from skimage import io, color, filter, exposure, morphology


img = color.rgb2gray(io.imread('7AEJTuA.jpg'))

threshold = filter.threshold_otsu(img)

img_bw = img < threshold

img_bw_thick = morphology.dilation(img_bw, morphology.disk(6))

plt.gray()
f, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax0.imshow(img)
ax1.imshow(img_bw_thick)
plt.show()
```

I see the following image:

[image]

Comment: To get rid of the noise pixels, you could also use http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html?highlight=remove_small#skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you do not use skimage's builtin Otsu function?

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
from skimage import io, color, filter, exposure


img = color.rgb2gray(io.imread('7AEJTuA.jpg'))
img_rescale = exposure.rescale_intensity(img, out_range=(0, 1))

threshold = filter.threshold_otsu(img_rescale)

plt.gray()
plt.imshow(img_rescale < threshold)
plt.show()
```

You may also have a look at `skimage.filter.rank.otsu` as an alternative...

Comment: I only shift the problem, beacuse the next line of my code is: img = mh.morph.close(img, disko) and now the image is like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371827/why-performing-an-histogram-equalization-by-scikit-image-to-a-binary-image-i-got/21383999?noredirect=1#comment32284340_21383999: Black image. If i use scikit dilation: img = dilation(img, disk(6)) the result is always black!Before dilation i have a uint16 array, after it is uint8:"Warning: Possible precision loss when converting from uint16 to uint8." I cast type by: gray=np.array(gray, dtype=np.uint16) but is always black!

Comment: Yes, you cannot scale images like that--you need to use ``img_as_float``, ``img_as_ubyte``, ``img_as_uint`` etc., which returns both the correct type and range.

Comment: I don't see the black image you are talking about.  I've added a dilation command to the above code, and see the dilated image as expected.  I'll post a new answer so that I can attach the image, although it should go here as a comment.